# not getting the desired output from an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to create an dynamic array and can't get it right.
I need something like this:

Product Name

- top
- - White
- - Black
- Bottom
- - Red
- - Green

I came up with this code, which is producing the above text, so my logic must be about right.

```
$set = array();
$set['name'] = "Product Name";

$options = array("top", "bottom");
$values['top'] = array("White", "Black");
$values['bottom'] = array("Red", "Green");

echo "<pre>".$set['name']."</pre>";
foreach ($options as $o) {
    echo "<pre>- $o</pre>";
    $set['options'][]['name'] = $o;

    foreach ($values[$o] as $v) {
        echo "<pre>-- $v</pre>";
        $set['options'][]['values']['name'] = $v;
    }
}
```

The array that is created with the above code is:

```
Array
(
  [name] => Product Name
  [options] => Array
  (
    [0] => Array
    (
     [name] => top
    )
[1] => Array
                (
                    [values] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => White
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [values] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Black
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => bottom
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [values] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Red
                        )

                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [values] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Green
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

THe output I want is:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Product Name
    [options] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => top
                    [values] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => White
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Black
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => bottom
                    [values] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Red
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Green
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: if you are creating array by yourself then you can create as desired output
`array('top' => array('top','bottom'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got

```
$set['options'][]['name'] = $o;
                ^
             this one
```

and

```
$set['options'][]['values']['name'] = $v;
                ^
             This one
```

in outer as well as inner loop which was adding new item to array (so there were indexes like 0, 1, 2 ...) so could not produce what you wanted.

You may correct your array like below:

[Demo](https://eval.in/902363)

```
<?php

$set = array();
$set['name'] = "Product Name";

$options = array("top", "bottom");
$values['top'] = array("White", "Black");
$values['bottom'] = array("Red", "Green");

echo "<pre>".$set['name']."</pre>";
foreach ($options as $o) {
    echo "<pre>- $o</pre>";

    $vals = array();
    foreach ($values[$o] as $v) {
        echo "<pre>-- $v</pre>";
         $vals[] = array('name' => $v );
    }
     $set['options'][] = array('name' => $o, 'values' => $vals );

}

print_r($set);

?>
```